# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, math, types

I am trying to use values from an array in the following equation:

```
for x in range(len(prof)):
    PB = 2.25 * (1 - math.pow(math.e, (-3.7(prof[x])/2.25))) * (math.e, (0/2.25)))
```

When I run I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cwpapine/Desktop/1mPro_Chlavg", line 240, in <module>
    PB = float(2.25 * (1 - math.pow(math.e, (-3.7(prof[x])/2.25))) * (math.e, (0/2.25)))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

What is the cause, and how can the problem be resolved?

Comment: you are missing an operation here : `-3.7(prof[x])` it should be `-3.7 * (prof[x])` or ...

Comment: I had the same exception in a class where I had a float attribute and a method with the same name. Renaming one of the two solved it for me

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is an operator missing, likely a `*`:

```
-3.7 need_something_here (prof[x])
```

The "is *not callable*" occurs because the parenthesis -- and lack of operator which would have switched the parenthesis into precedence operators -- make Python try to *call* the result of `-3.7` (a float) as a function, which is not allowed.

The parenthesis are also not needed in this case, the following may be sufficient/correct:

```
-3.7 * prof[x]
```

---

As Legolas points out, there are other things which may need to be addressed:

```
2.25 * (1 - math.pow(math.e, (-3.7(prof[x])/2.25))) * (math.e, (0/2.25)))
                                  ^-- op missing
                                                    extra parenthesis --^
               valid but questionable float*tuple --^
                                     expression yields 0.0 always --^
```

Comment: Note there are also more closing than opening parentheses and the second comma seems to be off.

Comment: Removing the parentheses did the trick in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten a `*` between `-3.7` and `(prof[x])`.

Thus:

```
for x in range(len(prof)):
    PB = 2.25 * (1 - math.pow(math.e, (-3.7 * (prof[x])/2.25))) * (math.e, (0/2.25)))
```

Also, there seems to be missing an `(` as I count 6 times `(` and 7 times `)`, and I think `(math.e, (0/2.25))` is missing a function call (probably `math.pow`, but thats just a wild guess).

Comment: thank you legolas and everyone else, I have noticed several typos in my equation.  Perhaps I need to take a break and let my eyes rest :-)

Comment: Please don't copy other people's answers

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `-3.7(prof[x])`, which looks like a function call (note the parens). Just use a `*` like this `-3.7*prof[x]`.

Comment: Please don't copy other people's answers.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be an answer to this question in particular, another reason you could get this error is if you have defined "range" as a variable.

```
range = 0
for x in range(len(array)): 
#will give an error, because it's trying to multiply "range" with "(len(array))"
```

The solution would be to rename your variable to a synonym (period) or append something to it (range1, range_a)

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered but for others, the reason for the same error might be highly possible due to the following reason:
Sometimes, when you use a variable name same as one of the inbuilt functions and when you try to call that inbuilt function later on, its gonna give you a type error.
For example, somewhere in your code you define a variable as:

> sum = 0

Maybe to use it as an accumulator variable in global dataframe.
Now, later when you're defining a function in which you want to call the inbuilt  function sum() , its gonna give an type error as you have over-written an in-built function name.
That's why, you should avoid the use in-built function names like **str, range, sum, etc..** as one of the variable names in your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).