# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable error with bhaskara program

Tags: python

```
#entrada de dados
a = int(input("valor de a "))
b = int(input("valor de b "))
c = int(input("valor de c "))
#
import math
#
d =b*b - 4 * a * c
#
if d < 0:
        print('nao tem raizes reais')
elif d ==0:
        raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
        print('o valor e '), print(raiz)
elif d > 0:
        raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))(2 * a)
        raiz1 = (-1*b - math.sqrt(d))(2 * a)
        print('as raizes sao'), print(raiz), print(raiz1)
#fim
```

I tried put this code but i got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Python34/test podre.py", line 16, in 
>       raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))(2 * a)
>   TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

what is wrong?

Comment: What do you think ? Have you tried to figure out what happens ? Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929777/typeerror-float-object-is-not-callable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You cannot multiply two objects in python by pure parentheses, you need to separate them with `*`.**

```
raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))(2 * a)
```

Becomes

```
raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))*(2 * a)
```

Here is your edited code:

```
a = int(input("valor de a "))
b = int(input("valor de b "))
c = int(input("valor de c "))
#
import math
#
d =b*b - 4 * a * c
#
if d < 0:
        print('nao tem raizes reais')
elif d ==0:
        raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
        print('o valor e '), print(raiz)
elif d > 0:
        raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))*(2 * a)
        raiz1 = (-1*b - math.sqrt(d))*(2 * a)
        print('as raizes sao'), print(raiz), print(raiz1)
```

Comment: Oh, missed that! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarcelaBittencourt, no problem :) Also, if this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it after 15 minutes (click the green check next to my answer)

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten the division sign in these lines:

```
    raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))(2 * a)
    raiz1 = (-1*b - math.sqrt(d))(2 * a)
```

it should be:

```
    raiz = (-1*b + math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
    raiz1 = (-1*b - math.sqrt(d))/(2 * a)
```