# Getting "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable" when using Math package

Tags: python, function, math, formula

I am trying to come up with a user-defined function that calculates probability density function with users' input for mean, variance and x-value.

This is my code:

```
def pdf(m, v, x):
    print((1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi(v))))*math.exp(-(((x-m)**2)/2*v)))

pdf(m, v, x)
```

However, after I call the function, I encountered this error:

> "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable". Any advice on how I can fix this, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'float' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929777/typeerror-float-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: The problem in your code is math.pi(v). math.pi is a float and not an callable object.  Something like math.pi*v will work. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html for more information about the math library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def pdf(m, v, x):
    print((1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi * v)))*math.exp(-(((x-m)**2)/2*v)))
```

You are actually passing (v) as actual parameter to pi. Pi doesn't accept any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
def pdf(m, v, x):
    print((1/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi*v)))*math.exp(-(((x-m)**2)/2*v)))
```

Comment: You already posted that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68647120/5468463